# C# ASP.Net Core Keeping the submitted file(s) after form submit failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

I want to keep the uploaded file(s) remained in `<input type="file" />` field when if `(!ModelState.IsValid)` is true due to some invalid values from other fields, and the validation error messages are shown back on the view. The textfield values are remained after the form submit failure, but the uploaded file(s) disappear from the file input field.

I have been looking for solutions for do so, but haven't found any yet. I would highly appreciate if anyone has a solution or suggestion for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The response from the form submission is a completely new page, and an HTML page cannot pre-select files in a file input, as that would pose a massive security risk.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may be able to use AJAX / [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to submit your form instead, which would avoid reloading the page. However, you would need to take complete control over the process from Javascript - redirecting if the submission succeeds, displaying error messages if it fails, etc.